# Converting nginx to Apache rewrites

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up Symfony from an existing site that's on nginx. My local machine is Apache and this is the redirect scheme on nginx. How do I write this using RewriteRules?

```
location / {
               # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
               try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
       }

       location @rewriteapp {
               # rewrite all to app.php
               rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
       }

       location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
               fastcgi_pass php_upstream; # Upstream on top of file
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
               # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
               try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
       }

       location @rewriteapp {
               # rewrite all to app.php
               rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
       }
```

The first part seems to be the only rewrite. This looks like it could be written as follows using mod_rewrite on Apache in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Enable trailing pathname information (if not already)
AcceptPathInfo On

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /app.php/$0 [L]
```

Internally rewrite all requests that don't map to physical files or directories to `/app.php/<requested-url-goes-here>`.

Since this uses trailing path information on the URL (`/$0`), you need to make sure that the server permits this, otherwise you'll get an immediate 404 Not Found. However, this generally is enabled by default (although it does depend on the handler).

Comment: This will result in a redirect loop

Comment: It shouldn't - `app.php` presumably exists as a physical file? The above rewrite only occurs if the requested file _does not exist_.

Comment: It is a local file

Comment: A "local file" in the document root I assume? Just to add, you will also need to ensure that trailing path information is also permitted (it should be by default) - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes. Calling http://example.com/app_dev.php/user/new is working now, but http://example.com/user/new not

Comment: Ensure that `FollowSymLinks` is also enabled. (And disable `MultiViews` whilst you're at it). I've updated my answer. Do you have any other directives in this .htaccess file? Any other .htaccess files?

Comment: Same problem as before and there shouldn't be any other .htaccess

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? Is it doing anything? 404? Change `[L]` to `[L,R=302]` temporarily to see if it redirects. Try adding any nonsense to the file - do you get an error?

Comment: "not working" means the String "File not found." gets sent to the client. There's no HTTP error code in the logfile, but "AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'"
Changing `[L]` to `[L,R=302]` results in a 404.

Comment: Changing `[L]` to `[L,R=302]` redirects the client to `http://example.com/app.php/var/www/web/issue/list` when the URL is `http://example.com/issue/list`

Comment: That would seem to suggest that you have other rewrites before this (in either .htaccess or the server config)? Just to confirm... these directives are in your `.htaccess` file, not the server config? Try changing the `RewriteRule` directive to: `RewriteRule .* /app.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

Comment: No they are in the web server config and I can't find any other rewrites...

Comment: mod_rewrite works differently in the server config to when used in per-directory/.htaccess files and since you tagged your question `.htaccess`, I assumed that is where you were placing these directives (which I also stated in my answer, "...in the root .htaccess file"). However, that only partly explains the redirect you are seeing. Does changing the directive to `%{REQUEST_URI}` make any difference? (Note that since this is in your server config, you'll need to restart your server after every change.)